# Finding UMP test for composite hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

> Let $(X_i)$ be iid from a distribution proportional to $x^{\theta}1_{(0,1)}(x)$.
> a) Find the most powerful test of size $\alpha$ of $H_0: \theta=0$ against $H_1: \theta=1$.

> b) Find the UMP test of size $\alpha$ of $H_0: \theta=0$ against $H_1: \theta>0$.

I have solved part a) it turns out the critical region is $\{-\sum\log x_i < F^{-1}(\alpha)\}$ where $F$ is the $\Gamma(n,1)$ cdf by the Neyman Pearson lemma.

I was hoping that I would get the same critical region when I replace $1$ with $\theta_0$ in the alternative hypothesis, but instead we get $\{ -\sum\log x_i < F^{-1}_{\theta_0}(\alpha)\}$ where $F_{\theta_0}$ is the $\Gamma(n,\theta_0)$ cdf.

If we could find a $\theta_1$ such that $F^{-1}_{\theta_1} (\alpha)$ is minimal, then the size of such a test would be $\alpha$ and it would have maximal power over all $\theta_0>0$ And we would be done.

Please don’t quote Rubin’s theorem I would like to understand this